# Github not ignoring files under the \bin\ and \obj\ directory

Tags: c#, github, gitignore

I am interested in Github ignoring some files, especially the `debug` binaries under the `\bin` and `\obj` directory.

My `.gitignore` is under the `\Github\Grasshopper-Tools` directory, and inside I have this snippet which theoretically should ignore them:

```
# Build results
[Dd]ebug/
[Dd]ebugPublic/
[Rr]elease/
x64/
build/
bld/
[Bb]in/
[Oo]bj/
```

[image]

Am I missing anything?

Comment: Have you already commited any file inside these directories?

Comment: Yes, I have. Just added this `.gitignore` today

Comment: try `git rm --cached -- bin/`. If it works, then do it for all directories that you list in you .gitignore.

Comment: Before I do this, could you explain to me what this does? It appears it recursively removes the cached items in bin?

Comment: Once you commit a file, .gitignore can't ignore it anymore. The only way you can make it work again (on this file) is when you `git rm` it. The `--cached` flag tell git to remove the file from the repository but keep it on disk.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139762/gitignore-file-not-ignoring?rq=1 According to this (with the same solution you have) I should commit before I do so.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46526/discussion-between-eduardo-de-matos-and-thegreencabbage)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add * after / for ignore all file inside a directory. In your case, ignore all bin folder will be bin/*

Also, you could use a template for c# project. See this template:  https://gist.github.com/kmorcinek/2710267

Comment: I have replaced my old one with the one in that link, but it still seems to not ignore them o.O http://puu.sh/6EUbJ/7ad1a6b235.png